# How to change the rotating direction of loaders and add text inside the loader in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have to make a loader that the inner loader static with only top and bottom, the middle loader rotates anti-clockwise, and the outer loader rotates clockwise. The word "POLYU" is included in the center of the inner loader. Can anyone help me to modify my code? I am a newbie in coding. Please give me some help.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.outerLoader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    animation: outerAnimate 3s linear infinite;
}

.middleLoader {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: middleAnimate 4s linear infinite;
}

.innerLoader {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    left: 22px;
    bottom: 22px;
    right: 22px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: static;
}

@keyframes outerAnimate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes middleAnimate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You use transform property in both class and animation. So, normal transform translate is replaced by the animation's one.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
body, .outerLoader, .middleLoader, .innerLoader {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.outerLoader {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    animation: outerAnimate 3s linear infinite;
}

.middleLoader {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    animation: middleAnimate 4s linear infinite;
}

.innerLoader {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    animation: innerAnimate 6s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes outerAnimate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes middleAnimate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(-540deg);
    }
}
@keyframes innerAnimate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(540deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="outerLoader">
<div class="middleLoader">
<div class="innerLoader">
POLYU
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```